# I want to display multiple objects inside an array using loop in Javascript in a specific id in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

**I want this to display in a specific id in html.**

```
document.write("<table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr><td><b>Stand Name</td><td><b>Owner</td><td><b>Sub Area</td></tr></thead><tbody>");

for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i].subAreatype == subAreaList[5]) {
        document.write(list[i].standName + "<br>");
    }
}

document.write("</tbody></table>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this to display in a specific id in html.

In this case, you need to capture this in a variable first and then set the innerHTML of that ID document.

```
var html = "<table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr><td><b>Stand Name</td><td><b>Owner</td><td><b>Sub Area</td></tr></thead><tbody>";

for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i].subAreatype == subAreaList[5]) {
        html += list[i].standName + "<br>";
    }
}

html += "</tbody></table>";
```

Now display this html in the specific id in the page

```
document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML = html;
```